# How to display an arrow in Horizontal Flat List to indicate presence of invisible scrollview contents

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist

In my ReactNative App i have a FlatList shows availability of a service as a timeline.
While implementing this, only a part of scrollview is visible on screen. How to set an arrow indicator to make users aware that this view is a scrollview and more content is there to scroll.

[image: FlatList is as shown in this picture. Here content after 4am is invisible and User is unaware that there is more content to scroll]

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by adding tow more views along with FlatList. I added linear gradient view, starting from white color to partially transparent white color, before the flatlist. Also a flipped view of the same at the ending of flatlist.
fir linear gradient i used react-native-linear-gradient.

final render looks like

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>

    <LinearGradient
        start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
        end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
        colors={["#FFFFFF00", "#FFFFFFFF"]}
        style={{
            height: "100%",
            width: 32,
        }}
    />

    <FlatList
        data={this.state.timeSlotes}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
            return <TimeSloteItem data={item} />;
        }} />

    <LinearGradient
        start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
        end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
        colors={["#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF00"]}
        style={{
            height: "100%",
            width: 32,
        }}
    />
</View>
```